# Week based count

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement to retrieve the data in the below fashion

```
Weeks  delay_count
0           6         
1           0
2           3
3           4
4           0
5           1           
6           0
7           0    
8           0       
9           0
10          2
11          0        
12          0      
13          0    
14          0
15          3
```

Here weeks is the hard coded column from 0 to 15 and delay_count is the derived column. I have a column `delay_weeks`. Based on the values in this column I need to populate the values in the `delay_count` column (derived column)

`delay_weeks` column values are below.

```
blank
blank 
blank 
2
10
5
blank 
3
2
10
2
3
3
3
0
0
15
22
29
```

Conditions:

- When `delay_weeks` is blank or 0 then count in the `delay_count` column should be 1
- When `delay_weeks` is 3 then in the `delay_count` column the count should be 1  under week 3
- When `delay_weeks` is 10 then in the `delay_count` column the count should be 1 under week 10
- When `delay_weeks` is greater than or equal to 15 then in the `delay_count` column the count should be 1 under week 15.

I wrote code like below

```
SELECT   "Weeks", a."delay_count"
    FROM (SELECT     LEVEL AS "Weeks"
                FROM DUAL
          CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 15) m,
         (SELECT   VALUE, COUNT (VALUE) AS "delay_numbers"
              FROM (SELECT CASE
                                          WHEN attr11.VALUE >= 15
                                             THEN '15'
                                          ELSE attr11.VALUE
                                       END
                                     VALUE
                      FROM docs,
                           (SELECT object_id, VALUE, attribute_type_id
                              FROM ATTRIBUTES
                             WHERE attribute_type_id =
                                      (SELECT attribute_type_id
                                         FROM attribute_types
                                        WHERE name_display_code =
                                                 'ATTRIBUTE_TYPE.DELAY IN WEEKS')) attr11
                     WHERE docs.obj_id = attr11.object_id(+)

          GROUP BY VALUE) a
   WHERE m."Weeks" = a.VALUE(+)
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Those are your requirements, but what is your programming question?

Comment: hi john, i have a report called Delay. in this report i need weeks and delay count.

Comment: That doesn't answer John's question. WHat have you tried? This site is to help with specific programming problems, not to write your code for you. You need to show at least some effort.

Comment: hi alex i wrote the below code

Comment: And what happened? Looks like at least three immediate issues... missing a `)` after the last `group by`; mismatch between `delay_count` and `delay_numbers` column names; and using `'15'` in your case (is the `value` column `varchar2` or `number`?). So are you getting errors that you can't resolve - and if so, what? Or do you get the wrong result when the errors are corrected?

Comment: Hi alex i was getting wrong results with my query. any way thanks for the help.

Comment: Again, 'wrong results' isn't all that helpful, especially when the code you provide won't run as it is. Please start providing more information in your questions, particularly relevant table definitions, sample data, expected and actual results, and error messages. You should also start upvoting and accepting answers on previous questions or people will be less inclined to help with future ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
  weeks,
  nvl(cnt, 0) as delay_count
from
  (select level-1 as weeks from dual connect by level < 17)
  left join (
    select 
      nvl(least(attr11.value, 15), 0) as weeks,
      count(0) as cnt
    from 
      DOCS 
      left join (
        ATTRIBUTES attr11 
        join ATTRIBUTE_TYPES atr_tp using(attribute_type_id)
      ) 
        on atr_tp.name_display_code = 'ATTRIBUTE_TYPE.DELAY IN WEEKS'
        and docs.obj_id = attr11.object_id
    group by nvl(least(attr11.value, 15), 0)
  ) using(weeks)
order by 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Reverse-engineering the relevant parts of the table definitions, I think this gives you what you want:

```
select t.weeks, count(delay) as delay_count
from (select level - 1 as weeks from dual connect by level <= 16) t
left join (
    select case when a.value is null then 0
        when to_number(a.value) > 15 then 15
        else to_number(a.value) end as delay
    from docs d
    left join (
        select a.object_id, a.value
        from attributes a 
        join attribute_types at on at.attribute_type_id = a.attribute_type_id
        where at.name_display_code = 'ATTRIBUTE_TYPE.DELAY IN WEEKS'
    ) a on a.object_id = d.obj_id
) delays on delays.delay = t.weeks
group by t.weeks
order by t.weeks;
```

With what I think is matching data I get:

```
     WEEKS DELAY_COUNT
---------- -----------
         0           6
         1           0
         2           3
         3           4
         4           0
         5           1
         6           0
         7           0
         8           0
         9           0
        10           2
        11           0
        12           0
        13           0
        14           0
        15           3
```

But obviously since you haven't given the real table structures I'm guessing a bit on the relationships. Obligatory [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/155de/2).

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff - indeed; I'd already noticed and updated to fix the attributes/attributes_type join. Thanks.